# to replace part of string in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have string

> /logoDown?path=logo/5402eca1b4a0e/Lighthouse.jpg&isLogo=1&fileType=jpg

Now i want to replace word `logo` with `sep/2014/09/03/past/`  so the new string will become

> /logoDown?path=sep/2014/09/03/past/5402eca1b4a0e/Lighthouse.jpg&isLogo=1&fileType=jpg

Thanks

Comment: What if there are several occurrences of the word? (There are, in fact.)

Comment: i just need to replace the word after path=